# How to recalculate normals?

Tags: normals

in version of Blender 2.72, where is the option recalculate?.

Like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPqxADetWE&feature=player_detailpage#t=108

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: If you don't see the Shading/UVs tab in the Tools menu, make sure you're in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 15):

'Toolbar tabs' were implemented in 2.70. You can recalculate the normals from the 'Shading/UVs' tab of the tool shelf (revealed with <kbd>T</kbd>), or you can do it by a short cut by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I don't see this menu