# New action button disabled

Tags: animation

I created a model of a knight in blender to use in a jMonkeyEngine game. I rigged it and used the timeline to make an animation.
Now I want to make another animation and I've heard I have to do that in the Action editor but when I go there the new action button is disabled. How do I create another animation for this model? [image: action button disabled]

Comment: Looks to me nothing is selected

Comment: @Tak Oh man I feel so dumb. Thank you so much! If you want to leave an answer, I'll mark it as such

Comment: no worries, we are all learning here :) Answer provided so if could mark it as solved :)

Comment: On another note, your normals appear inverted, try [recalculating normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/how-to-recalculate-normals), or selecting the darker faces and flipping normals. See [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are selecting an object/bone to be able to add action to it.