# Why does my completely green UV map make my model no completely green?

Tags: uv

[image]

Hello all,

Apologies for the bad title. I am very new to this! Basically I spent a while creating this model, and then after following a texturing turtorial, I have ended up with this mess. I wanted to check that the UV map does actually work. So I just filled my UV map with green, however my model isn't completely green? Why is this and how can I fix it??

Thank you.

Comment: The texture shaded mode it surely overlaying the default shading of the faces to the texture if you don't enable "shadeless" option. That said, there may be other things involved (wrong normals orientation, multiple materials...) Could you show your object also in solid mode view?

Comment: Where can I find this shadeless option and what does it do?? Also here is a link. I hope it works! http://imgur.com/a/mxK1q

Comment: Definitely something off with your normals.  Try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/how-to-recalculate-normals

Comment: Have in mind that you seem to be confusing a lot of different concepts. Your UV Map is not green, your texture is. UV maps don't hold color information. There is no material applied to your mesh unwraping ≠ texturing ≠ materials. Unwrapping your mesh doesn't give it color, UV maps are not materials, and textures can't be applied by themselves to an object, they need a material

Comment: @LukasValine I have recalculated my normals, but some faces are still black. Even if I flip the normals on those faces, they remain black.

Comment: Try removing double vertices and then recalculate your normals again.  In edit mode: W -> remove doubles

Comment: @LukasValine Thank you for your help, however some black faces still remain. When I removed doubles, there were 16 verticies removed. That did help, but as I said there are still black faces. Also some are darker, why would this be? If the texture map is all green, surely that would make the model all green right?? Or am I thinking about this wrong? Sorry, I am a noob!

Comment: Could you post your .blend file? https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Comment: @LukasValine Thank you! https://www.dropbox.com/s/frseakl641ipprv/RedPanda.blend?dl=0

Comment: So a couple things, I removed doubles, recalculated normals, set shading to smooth, removed a few extraneous edges around the ears, and cleaned up your topology a bit.  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3436/

Comment: @LukasValine Thank you very much! You have been so helpful! So even after I removed doubles, they are still there?? Thank you for your help. Any tips for future creations to stop this happening again??