# Texture on the wrong side of eyes after import from MakeHuman

Tags: texturing, uv, makehuman

I imported this model from MakeHuman, by exporting it as a `dae` and importing it into blender. This worked great, however there is one "glaring" (pardon the pun) problem. The model's eyes don't have any texture, as can be seen here:[image: No eye texture]

However, if I remove the eyes from the head and look inside them on the other side of the object, there's the texture!
[image: Eye texture inside]

I've tried flipping normals (by hitting space and typing flip normal and hitting enter) and recalculating them (by following the instructions here: [How to recalculate normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/how-to-recalculate-normals)).

Neither of these results in the eye textures being on the proper side. It looks proper in MakeHuman

Comment: The solution is to make sure that the texture **specular** color is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, you will see two layers in the eye. The exported MakeHuman model contains the cornea of the eye as well (the clear layer that covers the eye). In the viewport this appears white, but when rendering it should appear mostly transparent.

Comment: It does not appear properly in rendered mode either

Comment: It could be that the cornea material did not get exported. I haven't worked with MakeHuman in a long while. You can either add a material to the cornea or just remove it.

Comment: @lightbord Do not rely blindly on [Imported Materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Answer (score 0):

The fix in blender 2.9 is to select the eyeballs in object mode, select material properties, expand settings and on blend mode select 'Alpha Blend'.