# Weird problems when I extrude or try to shape vertices

Tags: modeling

So I start with a normal cube > I Extrude and it doesn't work right ( Grey faces and missing faces ) I try to move a face/vertices with G and right click but it selects some sort of ghost vertices. Help I can't solve this and it's making me want to give up Blender. I tried looking for solutions but it seems like it's a bug.

[image: The Problems that happen]

Comment: Ok, what version of blender are you using? Have you tried deleting the cube and starting over? It seem like you've got duplicated vertices that are conflicting.

Comment: @TechTornado I've tried starting over and restarting Blender. I'm using the version on Steam so it's most likely the recent version. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: To clarify: have  extruded successfully, using prior or other versions of blender?

Comment: Yeah it used to work fine

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a bug to me. There are [3 types of selection modes](https://youtu.be/YhZKz7Ab6_M) in blender; Vertex, Edge and Face. You have to select them according to your requirements. If you select any of them and press 'E' to extrude, it extrudes along the [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html) by default. If you want, you can constrain your extrusion to a specific axis by pressing 'E' to extrude and then X, Y or Z for x, y and z axis respectively.

The second problem you mentioned is shading problem according to me. After you've finished your extrusion and modelling, select the whole mesh in edit mode by pressing 'A' key and then [recalculate the normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/how-to-recalculate-normals).